# Organising large datasets in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array, organization, large-data-volumes, matlab-table

I have a problem I hope you can help me with.

I have imported a large dataset (200000 x 5 cell) in Matlab that has the following structure:

`'Year' 'Country' 'X' 'Y' 'Value'`

Columns 1 and 5 contain numeric values, while columns 2 to 4 contain strings.

I would like to arrange all this information into a variable that would have the following structure:

`NewVariable{Country_1 : Country_n , Year_1 : Year_n}(Y_1 : Y_n , X_1 : X_n)`

All I can think of is to loop through the whole dataset to find matches between the names of the `Country`, `Year`, `X` and `Y` variables combining the `if` and `strcmp` functions, but this seems to be the most ineffective way of achieving what I am trying to do.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write something that functions first, worry about optimization later.

Comment: Thanks for the hint excaza. The point is that there is probably a function I do not know that can be used to do that. Otherwise I will have to loop through the whole dataset every time I want to extract a concrete value and that is not a real alternative if, for example, instead of 200000 records, I have 5 million.

Comment: oh and there is! please take a look into categorical()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use categorical array:

```
% some arbitrary data:
country = repmat('ca',10,1);
country = [country; repmat('cb',10,1)];
country = [country; repmat('cc',10,1)];
T = table(repmat((2001:2005)',6,1),cellstr(country),...
    cellstr(repmat(['x1'; 'x2'; 'x3'],10,1)),...
    cellstr(repmat(['y1'; 'y2'; 'y3'],10,1)),...
    randperm(30)','VariableNames',{'Year','Country','X','Y','Value'});
% convert all non-number data to categorical arrays:
T.Country = categorical(T.Country);
T.X = categorical(T.X);
T.Y = categorical(T.Y);
% here is an example for using categorical array:
newVar = T(T.Country=='cb' & T.Year==2004,:);
```

The `table` class is made for such things, and very convenient. Just expand the logic statement in the last line `T.Country=='cb' & T.Year==2004` to match your needs.
Tell me if this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the useful response, @EBH! Importing the data as a table and using the categorical function is exactly what I needed. :-)